# Why does data-migration tool say "core_config_data" document doesn't exist?

Tags: magento2

This is what it reads but I do not understand why.

> [2016-10-10 17:40:20][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity
>   check][step: Settings Step]: started
>
> 100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
>
> [2016-10-10 17:40:20][ERROR]: Integrity check failed due to
>   "core_config_data" document does not exist in the source resource
>   [2016-10-10 17:40:20][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity
>   check][step: Stores Step]: started
>
> 100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
>
> [Migration\Exception] Integrity Check failed   migrate:settings
>   [-r|--reset] config

Answer (score 4):

My error was that I did not have a source prefix defined in config.xml file.

I had to change `<source_prefix />` to `<source_prefix>gfit_</source_prefix>`

Answer (score 2):

My error was that I did not have a Destination prefix defined in config.xml file.

I had to change `<dest_prefix /> to <dest_prefix>mg_</dest_prefix>`...

When i looked at the tables in phpmyadmin the magento 2 tables, all add a mg_ prefix.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check your source database and make sure those tables are there. It is possible you forgot to import/setup your source database.